# Tracking page postbacks in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have to hide certain fields when the page first loads but after the page is posted to the server on the first post I have to reload the page and display the fields and after page is submitted again then I have to redirect to another page. I was doing it through the below code

Setting the counter through this field

```
private int Step
{
    get { return (int)Session["step"]; }
    set { Session["step"] = value; }
}
```

In the Page Init setting it to 0

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
      if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if(Session["step"] == null || Step >= 2)
                Step = 0;               
            }   
}
```

In the button save event

```
 protected override void cmdNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            this.SaveViewModel();
            Step++;
            if (Step > 1)
            {
                base.cmdNext_Click(sender, args);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            }          

        }
```

This is working fine but the issue comes when the counter becomes 1 after the user saves the page but then instead of clicking on save again and increment the variable which would redirect the page to another page the user restarts the process and then gets to this page again but the counter value is 1 since it was not incremented so the fields that are supposed to be hidden gets displayed.

It is mostly because I am using Session to track the page count which is leading to this issue.

Can someone please tell me how to achieve the below scenario

1. Page loads first time -- some fields are hidden
2. Saved button is clicked and if this is the first time saved is clicked the same page loads and the hidden fields gets displayed.
3. After save is clicked again the counter resets and the page is redirected to another page.

   Page Loads -> Some fields Hidden
   Page is posted back -> Reload the same page with the hidden fields showing
   Page is saved again -> Redirected to another page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just check the visibility of fields

```
Page Loads -> Some fields Hidden
Page is posted back -> Reload the same page with the hidden fields showing
Page is saved again -> If a certain field (or fields) is/are visible, redirect.
```